# PDF options on displaying content and building

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Background: I am currently designing an app that is sorta like a registration page, What it does is take the users input from a UITextField and places it onto a PDF file.

The PDF File: This PDF file is already generated(I created using a pdf maker), it editable when you open it normally(Using just any pdf opener).

My troubles/questions: Currently in my view controller I have code that generates a pdf with just one user text field entry. I want to know if i wanted to get multiple text entry, should I do it as an array then pass it to the .draw CG model or any better way of doing it. My second question is there a way that I wouldn't have to draw this pdf file using swift, but to use the already created .pdf file I have as a template. I saw you could use a HTML template, but I'm confused if I would have to make the .pdf all over again, but not just using HTML code?
This is how far I am on my current code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var size = CGSize()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var myview: UITextField!

@IBAction func generatePDFButton(_ sender: Any)
{
size = CGSize(width: 850, height: 1100);
let filename: String = "Good.pdf";
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0];
let writePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent(filename).path
print(writePath)
generatepdf(filepath: writePath);



}

func generatepdf(filepath: String)
{
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filepath as String, CGRect.zero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 850, height: 1100), nil);
drawText();
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}


func drawText(){
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
let textRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 850, height: 1100);
let font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 14);
let text = myview.text;
let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle;
let textColor = UIColor.black;
let textFontAttributes =
[
    NSFontAttributeName : font!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle
];
text?.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes);
}
```

Any suggestion, tips, and guide appreciated.